# Entity Framework (.NET 6.0) dbcontext.Database.SetCommandTimeout(600) throws error - method not found

Tags: entity-framework-core

In the CRUD layer using Entity Framework Core 6.0 version throws an error while calling the stored procedure and setting the command time out parameter.

> Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerFloatTypeMapping..ctor(String storeType, Nullable`1 dbType, StoreTypePostfix storeTypePostfix)

.NET 6.0 nuget packages have been updated

Comment: The title suggests that `SetCommandTimeout` wasn't found. You should show the code that actually throws the exception and the essential parts of the class model and mapping configuration. It seems related to value conversions.

Comment: The fact that the exception doesn't occur (apparently) when not increasing the command timeout probably means that you get a timeout exception before EF gets to the point where value conversions are executed client-side. The command timeout itself is not part of the problem.

Comment: You are mixing different EF Core versions

Comment: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.10" />
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10" />
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.0.0" />
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.1" />
   "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
   "System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.4" /> can u please confirm any version change required here ? @ErikEj

Comment: This issue was solved after adding  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.10"> and changing namespace from system.data.sqlclient to microsoft.data.sqlclient. @gertarnold